# DynamoDB putting item using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying the AWS CLI with local DynamoDB.

While I was working, I found some issues.

[Inserting & Retrieving Items | DynamoDB, explained.](https://www.dynamodbguide.com/inserting-retrieving-items) shows how to create a table using JSON format. But it didn't work for me. So I had to  use [Basic Operations for Tables - Amazon DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithTables.Basics.html). Anyways, it worked.

But what was the trouble was when putting an item.

I tried to add item to the local db like this:

```
aws dynamodb put-item \
    --table-name UsersTable \
    --item '{
      "Username": {"S": "alexdebrie"}
    }' \
    --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

But there was an error like this:

> Unknown options: {S:, alexdebrie}, }', Username:

How can I handle this?

PS: I am using Windows so instead of `\`, I used `^`.

Comment: Error you see is apparently a formatting error. Did you try it without using escaping characters in a single string?

Comment: I tried it of course, but it still showed the same error.

Answer (score 10):

Here is an one-line example that works on Windows:

```
aws dynamodb put-item --table-name test --item "{\"id\":{\"S\":\"mars\"},\"miles\":{\"N\":\"999\"}}"
```

So, in your case:

```
aws dynamodb put-item --table-name UsersTable --item "{\"Username\":{\"S\":\"alexdebrie\"}}" --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

A few things to note:

- try to avoid multiple lines in your command
- include the entire item in double-quotes
- precede every double-quote *within* the item with a backslash e.g. `\"id\"`
- if your attribute value is numeric, you must still quote its value for example `\"N\":\"999\"`

I feel your pain. It's horrible.

You might want to also consider supplying parameters in a JSON file using `--cli-input-json`

Answer (score 6):

Try with git bash, that solved my problem. I was using cmd from windows and i was facing the same problem with the formatting. The same command works in git bash.

Comment: That's the easiest workaround. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One thing that might help Mac and Linux users, try a [heredoc](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html).

Consider the following example table:

```
$ aws dynamodb create-table \
--table-name MNLakes \
--key-schema AttributeName=LakeID,KeyType=HASH \
--attribute-definitions AttributeName=LakeID,AttributeType=S \
--provisioned-throughput ReadCapacityUnits=1,WriteCapacityUnits=1
```

Now we will add some data for [Lake Nokomis](https://www.dnr.state.mn.us/lakefind/lake.html?id=27001900).

```
$ aws dynamodb put-item --table-name MNLakes --item "{\"LakeID\": {\"S\": \"27001900\"}}"
```

Escaping the double quotes in the JSON is OK for simple items.  However, for anything more complicated, it gets rather unpleasant.  A good solution might be to try a [heredoc](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html):

```
$ aws dynamodb put-item --table-name MNLakes --item "$(cat << EOF
{
  "LakeID":
    {
      "S": "36000800"
    },
  "Sasquatch":
    {
      "S": "YES"
    },
  "LastLakeSurvey":
    {
      "S": "2016"
    } 
}
EOF
)"
```

Results here:

```
$ alex@DESKTOP-VG47CLN:~$ aws dynamodb scan --table-name MNLakes
{
    "Items": [
        {
            "Sasquatch": {
                "S": "YES"
            },
            "LakeID": {
                "S": "36000800"
            },
            "LastLakeSurvey": {
                "S": "2016"
            }
        },
        {
            "LakeID": {
                "S": "27001900"
            }
        }
    ],
    "Count": 2,
    "ScannedCount": 2,
    "ConsumedCapacity": null
}
```

While the old `cmd.exe`/Batch syntax doesn't support anything that elegant, [PowerShell does](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html)

Comment: if u have $ in value, then it's not for you..

Answer (score 1):

in place of `"` put `\"`

use like this

```
aws dynamodb put-item \
    --table-name UsersTable \
    --item '{
      \"Username\": {\"S\": \"alexdebrie\"}
    }' \
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is specific in only on windows not on Mac or linux. But I agree with @Jnana Palai. But make sure the JSON is also enclosed in " not '

Likewise:
aws dynamodb put-item 
--table-name UsersTable 
--item "{
"Username": {"S": "alexdebrie"}
}" \

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows 10 the best way to permanently deal with this (recurrent) problem is to install Windows Subsystem for Linux ([WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10)) with an Ubuntu system, and then install AWS CLI for Linux as here ([AWS CLI Ubuntu](https://linuxhint.com/install_aws_cli_ubuntu/)). Once you've done this you can use the ~95% of AWS CLI snippets online that are from Linux systems, and all the horrible quoting/escaping nonsense just vanishes! (Also you get the huge benefit of having Linux inside your Windows system)

Answer (score 0):

```
json='{"pets": {"cat": "lucy"},"fur":{"color": "brown"}}'
pets=$(printf "$json" "$pets" "$fur")
```

```
aws dynamodb put-item --table-name table-name --item "$pets"
```

the error you got was from the shell splitting your variable, you can wrap it in double quotes to prevent that.

```
user='{"Username": {"S":"alexdebrie"}}'
formattedUser=$(printf "$user" "$Username")
```

```
aws dynamodb put-item --table-name UsersTable --item "$formattedUser" --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use a json file:

```
awslocal dynamodb put-item --table-name your-table-name --item "$(cat dynamo-data/my-mock-data.json)"
```

I hope that helps.